# sql вывести название категорий и посчитать количество товаров в данной категории

Tags: mysql, sql

Проблема такова есть у меня список категорий, к категориям необходимо написать количество товаров отвечающие даным категориям.

[image: конечный результат]

В базе данных имеются 2 таблицы

---

- +Product
- |_id
- |_name
- |_category_id
- |_article

---

- +Category
- |_id
- |_category_id
- |_name

---

Посчитать количество товаров - просто.

```
SELECT category_id as category, count(*) AS cnt
FROM product 
GROUP BY category_id
```

В результате мы получим таблицу вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

category: 1 2 3 4 5 ... в общем номера категорий
cnt: ... количества товаров в категориях

Как мне сделать пересчет товаров и сопоставить колонку "category_id" таблицы product с колонкой "name" таблицы Category(названия категорий) в одном запроса?

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT category_id as category, count(*) AS cnt
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category on product.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY category_id
```

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT fid AS category, COUNT(*) AS cnt, cname FROM
    (SELECT product.category_id AS fid, category.name AS cname, category.id AS cid FROM category
    LEFT JOIN category on product.category_id = category.category_id) newtable
GROUP BY cid, cname
```

В общем с SQL я не силен, буду рад любой помощи.

---

Ответ

```
SELECT category.name as category, count(*) AS cnt
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category on product.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY category.category_id
```

Comment: Ну вот после первого "пробовал так" запрос то правильный, только почему вы выводите колонку category_id если вам нужно наименование. выводите те колонки которые вам нужны

Comment: "_Как мне сделать пересчет товаров и сопоставить колонку "category" таблицы product_" вы чуть выше описали структуру таблиц и там нет никакой колонки "category" о чем речь то идет, может вы имели ввиду "_name" или вы просто о сопоставлении по "caregory_id" которое вы в общем то и написали ?

Comment: Извиняюсь, то я перепутал. Там в запросе просто идет строка category_id as category после чего создается колонка category с последовательной номерацией. Я имею введу колонку category_id, там у меня хранятся номера категорий, а их описания в таблице category - name

Comment: "выводите те колонки которые вам нужны" вы имеете ввиду
GROUP BY category ? - получаю ошибку #1052 - Столбец 'category_id' в field list задан неоднозначно

Comment: Используйте `SELECT category.category_id as category, count(*) AS cnt` вместо `SELECT category_id as category, count(*) AS cnt`.

Comment: Ну да, он у вас в двух таблицах одинаково называется, в таких случаях всегда пишите колонку с именем таблицы, что бы sql понял какую из них вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Я почему-то думал что они какраз и должны называтся одинаково))) Всем спасио за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так должно все нормально работать:

```
SELECT c.name AS category, count(*) AS cnt
FROM product AS p
INNER JOIN category c ON p.category_id = c.category_id
GROUP BY p.category_id
```

Мой результат:

```
"Category 01" => 2
"Category 02" => 3
"Category 03" => 4
```

Comment: Спасибо! Какраз, когда ребята помогли справится с ошибкой ***#1052 - Столбец 'category_id' в field list задан неоднозначно*** Набросал свой вариант похожий на Ваш.

Comment: SELECT category.category_id as category, category.name, count(*) AS cnt
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category on product.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY category.category_id